How to get file's timestamps with 100-nanosecond resolution using wmic?
NTFS has 100-nanosecond resolution on Windows. Using wmic datafile to get a file's timestamps returns only microsecond resolution. How do I use wmic to get the complete, exact timestamps? If it cannot so that, then what command line method can?

NTFS has 100-nanosecond resolution on Windows that's the limit of NTFS and has nothing to do with Windows, it has that resolution on any platforms

Though it would be meaningless, just examine the NTFS drive data in a hex editor and interpret the values stored. NTFS.com, Forensic Focus and other sites cover NTFS date-time format and it's evaluation.
Of course, comparing the date-times is of limited use for a number of reasons.

Modern operating systems are multithreaded, and one thread could block another from accessing the file system for a time.
Most media rely on write caching. Is the date-time recorded that when the file was entered into the queue, or when it was actually written to storage, or some other value?
Some media has very high latency. It might take considerable time to even spin up a hard disk drive, much less record data, and though latency in a flash drive is lower, write time is often longer.
Does the OS even use the least-significant digits? They might be some arbitrary or random value.


I'm not able to script that.

wmic is deprecated. There won't be any further development to fix its issues and limitations. Just use PowerShell instead
$file = Get-Item -Path $filePath

"CreationTime:   {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff}" -f $file.CreationTime
"LastAccessTime: {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff}" -f $file.LastAccessTime
"LastWriteTime:  {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff}" -f $file.LastWriteTime

PowerShell allows accessing Win32 APIs and .NET framework methods directly so it can represent all the things in the API including file time, to exact the native resolution. However see the note in the documentation, the result might be exact at the file save moment due to the limitation of the process tick cycle

The "fffffff" custom format specifier represents the seven most significant digits of the seconds fraction; that is, it represents the ten millionths of a second in a date and time value.
Although it's possible to display the ten millionths of a second component of a time value, that value may not be meaningful. The precision of date and time values depends on the resolution of the system clock. On the Windows NT 3.5 (and later) and Windows Vista operating systems, the clock's resolution is approximately 10-15 milliseconds.

